# Rails: Order by sum of two columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sql-order-by

So, I have a `Photo` model which can be downloaded at `full_size` and `presentation_size`. When a user downloads a photo I track this on the photo's `full_downloads` and `presentation_downloads` attribute.

That's all good.

Sometimes I want to know how many total downloads there have been. I have a simple method, `total_downloads` which looks like so:

```
def total_downloads
  self.full_downloads + self.presentation_downloads
end
```

**My question is:** I would like to be able to order photos by all three of these (full, presentation, total downloads). The first two are easy, but how do you do an order by the sum of two columns? Note this needs to be both SQLite and PG compatible at minimum.

A side question, would it be faster to make the `total_downloads` method a query, and if so what's the best way to write that? I know to sum on the class you can call `Photo.sum(...)`, but I'm not sure how to do that for two columns on a single record.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be OK with writing the SQL directly or would that be an issue?

Comment: @Devin M - I'll do what I gotta do :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Photo.order('full_downloads + presentation_downloads')
```

It will run this SQL query:

```
SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" ORDER BY full_downloads + presentation_downloads
```

This is potentially slow though. If you have a large dataset and use this sort order often, you should consider creating a `total_downloads` column and recalculating its value if the record's `full_downloads` or `presentation_downloads` column changes.

Answer (score 3):

`Photo.order('full_downloads + presentation_downloads DESC')`

That would definitely be much faster than doing the sort in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

You now might have to add `Photo.order(Arel.sql('full_downloads + presentation_downloads'))` to avoid [UnknownAttributeReference error](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/UnknownAttributeReference.html)