# Using ".order(params[])" with a instance method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Post`, `Reply` and a `Vote` model (polymorphic):

```
 create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content",       :limit => 255
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                  :null => false
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "replies_count",                :default => 0, :null => false
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  create_table "replies", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "votes", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "votable_id"
    t.string   "votable_type"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "polarity"
    t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
  end
```

I needed the `total_votes` of posts and replies so I created an instance method:

**post.rb and reply.rb:**

```
  def total_votes
    self.votes.map {|v| v.polarity }.sum
  end
```

So I can use it to sort posts and replies:

**homepage:**

```
 default_order = "created_at DESC"
 params[:order_by] ||= default_order
 @feed_items = @post.replies.paginate(page: params[:page],
                                      per_page: 10).order(params[:order_by])
```

So now, I'm not very sure what do add after `order_by` in the view:

```
  <span><%= link_to 'total_votes DESC', root_path(order_by: HERE) %></span>
```

I tried `&:total_votes DESC` and `total_votes DESC` but didn't work.

What's the right way of doing this? (I thought it was a bit of unnecessary to add a `total_votes` column to both `posts` and `replies` tables, but not sure if that is better for performance?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with using the database to do the summing for you, but this is a little bit tricky because you need to order by a value that is calculated (an "aggregate"), but let's set that aside.

Your view will display items in the order determined when the instance variable is set in the *controller*.  So in the controller, you may detect that there's an `order_by` parameter (e.g. `/feed?order_by=total_votes`, and load the `@feed_items` accordingly, e.g.

```
def index
  if params[:order_by] && params[:order_by] == 'total_votes'
    sort_order = "total_votes DESC"
  else
    sort_order = "created_at DESC"
  end
  @feed_items = @post.replies.paginate(page: params[:page],
                                  per_page: 10).order(sort_order)
end
```

then in your view, to *change* the sort order, create a `link_to` that adds the query string parameter (see the last example in [the link_to api doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), e.g.

```
<%= link_to "Sort by Total Votes", root_path(:order_by => 'total_votes') %><br />
<%= link_to "Sort by Time", root_path %><br />
```

Your other question is about how to do the sorting by votes.  This answer may provide a good start for that, and an answer to your performance question: [Rails: Order by sum of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116772/rails-order-by-sum-of-two-columns)

Comment: So, I have to add a `total_votes` column to the posts table and another `total_votes` column to the replies table before implementing your code? I'm aware that `:order_by => 'total_votes'` works with existing tables in the db. I just don't know how to do it with instance methods.

Comment: I just edited the answer.  I think "no", you should calculate the total using `sum` on the fly.  This might be a good case for a scope on the Votes model that you could invoke from your model (passing the required information), then replacing the `.order()` predicate.

Comment: I see, could you give me an example of the scope on the Votes model?

Comment: Check this section of the Rails guide on scopes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments

Comment: Ok, I checked it out. So I have to write a SQL statement to get the sum of the votes? Or use my current instance method but add scope at the very beginning?

Comment: Here's another example that demonstrates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526012/order-players-on-the-sum-of-their-association-model

Comment: Thanks, I will try to figure out how to write the scope.